# transfer byte array by chunk over webservice asmx

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, console-application, asmx

I am working on a legacy webservice that are used to transfer zip files between server, it works fine until recently where the size of files become larger, more than 700 mb. This causes exceptions as my console application (client) are not able to receive large byte array send by the webservice at once, so i tried to send and receive the byte array by chunk, but the zip file ended up being corrupt and cannot be unzipped, below is what i have tried, i am a bit unfamiliar with webservice so would appreciate if you guys can point out my mistake or maybe point me to a better solution :

console app(original) :

```
 string saveto = MdlMain.FileName;
                object file = (object)serviceSoapClient.GetFile( saveto);
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(GlobalVariable.FileDirectory + str2, FileMode.Create);
                fileStream.Write((byte[])file, 0, Conversions.ToInteger(NewLateBinding.LateGet(file, (Type)null, "Length", new object[0], (string[])null, (Type[])null, (bool[])null)));
                fileStream.Flush();
                fileStream.Close();
```

webservice (original) :

```
        public byte[] GetFile( string strFilename)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(this.DJDownloadPath + strFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        long length = fileStream.Length;
        byte[] array = new byte[checked((int)(length + 1L - 1L) + 1)];

        fileStream.Read(array, 0, checked((int)length));
        fileStream.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;

        return array;

    }
```

Console app (Modified):

```
 FileStream fileStream= new FileStream(@"D:\example.zip", FileMode.Create);

                    int totalchunkNo = targetfilesize / 2000000;
                    int remainder = targetfilesize % 2000000;

                    if (remainder > 0 && remainder != totalchunkNo)
                        totalchunkNo++;

                    for (int i = 1; i <= totalchunkNo; i++)
                    {

                        byte[] bytetobeWritten = (byte[])serviceSoapClient.GetFileByChunk(MdlMain.FileName, i);

                        fileStream.Write(bytetobeWritten, 0, Conversions.ToInteger(NewLateBinding.LateGet(bytetobeWritten, (Type)null, "Length", new object[0], (string[])null, (Type[])null, (bool[])null)));
                       
                    }

                    fileStream.Flush();
                    fileStream.Close();
```

webservice (Modified):

```
[WebMethod]
    public byte[] GetFileByChunk(string strFilename, int requestChunkNo)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(this.DJDownloadPath + strFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        long length = fileStream.Length;
        byte[] array = new byte[length];
        int incomingOffset = 0;
        int chunkSize = 2000000;

        fileStream.Read(array, 0, (int)length);
        fileStream.Close();

        int currentchunkNo = 0;
        byte[] outboundBuffer = new byte[chunkSize];

        while (incomingOffset < array.Length)
        {
            int lengthh = Math.Min(outboundBuffer.Length, array.Length - incomingOffset);

            Buffer.BlockCopy(array, incomingOffset,
                             outboundBuffer, 0,
                             lengthh);

            incomingOffset += lengthh;

            currentchunkNo++;

            if (currentchunkNo == requestChunkNo)
            {
                return outboundBuffer;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the original code that worked for smaller files?

Comment: @user9938, i have included the original code